# Single Raspberry Pi to aid my PC in rendering - Practical?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

With all the talk about cheaper render farms with RPi custers and the surprising amount of RAM in the Pi 4 (up to 4 GB), would it be practical to get a single one to 'help' my pc in rendering cycles? or are they really only helpful in clusters?

Also, how would that compare to simply getting a better graphics card as opposed to my integrated one?

My specs: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, Intel Core i5-2400 @3.1GHz, 8GB RAM

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143670/feasibility-of-raspberry-pi-4-render-farm and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77574/blender-build-for-raspberry-pi3. In addition, I think that the overhead of scene transfer etc vs the speed of the Pi is unlikely to make this worth while.